# flutter : How to multi image upload firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, imagepicker

I'm uploading an image to the Firebasefirestore using multiImagePicker.
Now, I must select five images to upload. If not, the upload will not be executed due to a null error.

I want to upload to Firebase Firestore regardless of the number of images.
I think I will upload imageUrl in List format, but I don't know how.

Please let me know how to upload the image in the form of List.

```html
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:sample_sns_login/dialog/loadingAlertDialog.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;
import 'package:egg/groballyVariable.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart' as handler;
import 'package:egg/src/categories/openEgg.dart';

import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class OpenUploadScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const OpenUploadScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OpenUploadScreenState createState() => _OpenUploadScreenState();
}

class _OpenUploadScreenState extends State<OpenUploadScreen> {
  getPermission() async {
    if (await handler.Permission.contacts.request().isGranted) {
      // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
    } else {
// You can request multiple permissions at once.
      Map<handler.Permission, handler.PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
        handler.Permission.storage,
      ].request();
      print(statuses[handler.Permission.location]);
    }
  }

  bool uploading = false, next = false;

  double val = 0;
  late CollectionReference imageRef;
  late firebase_storage.Reference ref;
  String imageUrls = "",
      imageUrls1 = "",
      imageUrls2 = "",
      imageUrls3 = "",
      imageUrls4 = "",
      imageUrls5 = "";

  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  final List<XFile> _selectedFiles = [];
  final firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage _storageRef =
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final List<String> _arrImageUrls = [];
  int uploadItem = 0;
  static bool _isUploading = false;

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String userName = "";
  String userPhone = "";
  String itemCost = "";
  String itemModel = "";
  String itemColor = "";
  String description = "";
  String postid = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            next ? "에그정보를 적어주세요" : "사진을 넣어주세요",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, letterSpacing: 2),
          ),
          actions: [
            next
                ? Container()
                : ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "업로드",
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_selectedFiles.length == 5) {
                        setState(() {
                          next = true;
                          uploading = true;
                        });
                      } else {
                        Get.snackbar("이미지 업로드 에러", "5개의 이미지가 필요합니다.");
                      }
                    }),
          ],
        ),
        body: next
            ? SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      _eggtitleField(),
                      _eggdateField(),
                      _eggtopicField(),
                      _eggletterField(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 24,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 300,
                        height: 70,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (con) {
                                    return LoadingAlertDialog(
                                        message: "에그를 심고 있어요...");
                                  });
                              String postUId = const Uuid().v1();


                                uploadImgFile().whenComplete(() {
                                  Map<String, dynamic> addData = {
                                    'userName': userName,
                                    'uid': auth.currentUser!.uid,
                                    'email': auth.currentUser!.email,
                                    'userPhone': userPhone,
                                    'productsCost': itemCost,
                                    'productColor': itemColor,
                                    'productModel': itemModel,
                                    'Description': description,
                                    'urlImage1': _arrImageUrls[0].toString(),
                                    'urlImage2': _arrImageUrls[1].toString(),
                                    'urlImage3': _arrImageUrls[2].toString(),
                                    'urlImage4': _arrImageUrls[3].toString(),
                                    'urlImage5': _arrImageUrls[4].toString(),
                                    'getUserProfuleImg': getUserImgUrl,
                                    'getUserName': getUserName,
                                    'address': fullAddress,
                                    'lat': position!.latitude,
                                    'lng': position!.longitude,
                                    'time': DateTime.now(),
                                    'status': 'active',
                                    'eggimage':
                                        'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eggholderflutter.appspot.com/o/working%2Ffl_app_icon.png?alt=media&token=d71bcda1-1735-41f4-a5f8-972438',
                                    'eggname': "오픈에그",
                                    'postId': postUId,
                                    'likes': [],
                                    'follower': follower
                                  };

                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection("followproducts")
                                      .doc(postUId)
                                      .set(addData);
                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection("openproducts")
                                      .doc(postUId)
                                      .set(addData)
                                      .then((value) {
                                    print("data added success");
                                    Get.to(OpenProductsPage());
                                  }).catchError((error) {
                                    print("error");
                                  });
                                });
                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Color(0xFFFFCE7B),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                              ),
                              elevation: 3.0,
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                              child: Text(
                                '에그심기',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontFamily: 'dk',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Color(0xff6e1d23)),
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Stack(
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: _isUploading
                            ? showLoading()
                            : Column(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 30,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "에그홀더 _ 오픈에그",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'namu',
                                          fontSize: 30,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 16,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "오픈에그에 심을 사진을",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'dk',
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "5장 선택해주세요.",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'dk',
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 10,
                                  ),
                                  _selectedFiles.isEmpty
                                      ? const Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
                                          child: Text("이미지가 없습니다."),
                                        )
                                      : Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
                                          child: Text("이미지가 선택되었습니다. :" +
                                              _selectedFiles.length.toString()),
                                        ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        selectedImage();
                                        getPermission();
                                      },
                                      child: GridView.builder(
                                          itemCount: _selectedFiles.isEmpty
                                              ? 1
                                              : _selectedFiles.length,
                                          gridDelegate:
                                              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                                  crossAxisCount: 2),
                                          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                              Container(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.all(
                                                              Radius.circular(
                                                                  30)),
                                                      border: Border.all(
                                                          color: Colors.grey
                                                              .withOpacity(
                                                                  0.3))),
                                                  child: Stack(
                                                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                                                    children: [
                                                      _selectedFiles.isEmpty
                                                          ? Icon(
                                                              CupertinoIcons
                                                                  .camera,
                                                              color: Colors.grey
                                                                  .withOpacity(
                                                                      0.3),
                                                            )
                                                          : Image.file(
                                                              File(
                                                                  _selectedFiles[
                                                                          index]
                                                                      .path),
                                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                            ),
                                                      Positioned(
                                                        top: 5,
                                                        right: 4,
                                                        child: Container(
                                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                              255,
                                                              255,
                                                              244,
                                                              0.5),
                                                          child: IconButton(
                                                            icon: Icon(
                                                                CupertinoIcons
                                                                    .delete),
                                                            onPressed: () {
                                                              _selectedFiles
                                                                  .removeAt(
                                                                      index);
                                                              setState(() {});
                                                            },
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ))),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                      ),
                      uploading
                          ? Center(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "업로딩",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 12,
                                  ),
                                  CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    value: val,
                                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                        Colors.green),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          : Container(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  uploading
                      ? Center(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "업로딩",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 12,
                              ),
                              CircularProgressIndicator(
                                value: val,
                                valueColor:
                                    AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(),
                ],
              ));
  }

  final TextEditingController eggTitleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController eggTopicController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController eggletterController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController eggdateController = TextEditingController();

  Widget _eggtitleField() {
    const maxLines = 5;

    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: maxLines * 15.0,
        child: TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 23, fontFamily: "namu", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          autofocus: false,
          controller: eggTitleController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value!.isEmpty) {
              return ("에그에 심을 편지 제목을 적어주세요.");
            }
            return null;
          },
          onChanged: (value) {
            userName = value;
          },
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.tickets),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 15, 20),
              hintText: "에그캡슐 제목",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              )),
          maxLines: 1,
          minLines: 1,
        ));
  }

  Widget _eggdateField() {
    const maxLines = 5;

    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: maxLines * 15.0,
        child: TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 23, fontFamily: "namu", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          autofocus: false,
          controller: eggdateController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value!.isEmpty) {
              return ("에그를 심는 날짜를 적어주세요. ex) 20xx.xx.xx");
            }
            return null;
          },
          onChanged: (value) {
            userPhone = value;
          },
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.calendar),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 15, 20),
              hintText: "에그캡슐 심는 날짜",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              )),
          maxLines: 1,
          minLines: 1,
        ));
  }

  Widget _eggtopicField() {
    const maxLines = 5;

    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: maxLines * 15.0,
        child: TextFormField(
          autofocus: false,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 23, fontFamily: "namu", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          controller: eggTopicController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value!.isEmpty) {
              return ("에그에 심을 편지의 주제문구를 적어주세요.");
            }
            return null;
          },
          onChanged: (value) {
            itemColor = value;
          },
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.signature),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 15, 20),
              hintText: "에그캡슐 주제",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              )),
          maxLines: 1,
          minLines: 1,
        ));
  }

  Widget _eggletterField() {
    const maxLines = 5;

    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: maxLines * 30.0,
        child: TextFormField(
          autofocus: false,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 23, fontFamily: "namu", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          controller: eggletterController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value!.isEmpty) {
              return ("에그에 심을 편지를 적어주세요.");
            }
            return null;
          },
          onChanged: (value) {
            itemModel = value;
          },
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.text_bubble),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 15, 20),
              hintText: "에그캡슐 편지",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              )),
          maxLines: null,
          minLines: 5,
        ));
  }

  Widget showLoading() {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Uploading : " +
              uploadItem.toString() +
              "/" +
              _selectedFiles.length.toString()),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }



  Future uploadImgFile() async {
    int i = 1;
    for (var img in _selectedFiles) {
      setState(() {
        val = i / _selectedFiles.length;
      });

      ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("Image/ ${Path.basename(img.path)}");
      await ref.putFile(File(img.path)).whenComplete(() async {
        await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
          _arrImageUrls.add(value);
          i++;

        });
      });
    }

  }

  Future<String> uploadFile(XFile _image) async {
    firebase_storage.Reference reference =
        _storageRef.ref().child("multiple_images").child(_image.name);
    firebase_storage.UploadTask uploadTask =
        reference.putFile(File(_image.path));
    uploadTask.whenComplete(() {
      uploadItem++;
      if (uploadItem == _selectedFiles.length) {
        _isUploading = false;
        uploadItem = 0;
      }
    });

    return await reference.getDownloadURL();
  }

  Future<void> selectedImage() async {
    try {
      final List<XFile>? imgs = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
      if (imgs!.isNotEmpty) {
        _selectedFiles.addAll(imgs);
      }
      print("선택된 사진 갯수 : " + imgs.length.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      print("Something Wrong." + e.toString());
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
 if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        Uri[] uri=new Uri[images.size()];
        for (int i =0 ; i < images.size(); i++) {
            uri[i] = Uri.parse("file://"+images.get(i).path);
            storageRef = storage.getReference("photos");
            final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child(uri[i].getLastPathSegment());
            ref.putFile(uri[i])
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            String content = downloadUrl.toString();
                            if (content.length() > 0) {
                                editWriteMessage.setText("");
                                Message newMessage = new Message();
                                newMessage.text = content;
                                newMessage.idSender = StaticConfig.UID;
                                newMessage.idReceiver = roomId;
                                newMessage.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message/" + roomId).push().setValue(newMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

    }
```